# Visual Studio/C# - Which build action should I use for an ini file included in my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am still very new to C# and Visual Studio. I'm building an application which interacts with a database, and am using an INI file class to create and store application specific settings/preferences. Specifically, we have a CSV file containing the name of current projects and the project folder where the project specific INI file should be stored.

I have therefore got a TextBox used to store the path to this CSV file, so that my application can read the CSV file and present the user with a ComboBox containing the names of the current projects.

I have created an empty INI file (AppSettings.ini) in the root of the project folder which looks as below.

```
[Application_Settings]
Projects_List_CSV=
```

I have added this to my solution (Add > Existing Item).

I also have a **global.cs** Class which stores the path to this Ini file.

```
class global
{
   public static string AppIniFile = Application.StartupPath + @"\AppSettings.ini";
}
```

The INI file class I'm using will just read/write to the INI file to set the "Projects_List_CSV" key value.
e.g.

```
var AppIni = new IniFile(global.AppIniFile);
stringCurrent = AppIni.Read("Projects_List_CSV", "Application_Settings");
// If path is not set or is different to the existing path, recreate the section
if (txtProjectsListPath.Text != stringCurrent)
{
   AppIni.DeleteSection("Application_Settings");
   AppIni.Write("Projects_List_CSV", txtProjectsListPath.Text, "Application_Settings");
}
```

I know some of the above information may be irrelevant to my question, but my question is, in order for me to be able to read/write to this file at runtime, what "Build Action" do I need to apply to the AppSettings.ini file I've added to the solution?

Do I leave it as "None" and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer"?

I just need to file to be stored somewhere that's easy to recall/read when the app is running.

The main reason I have asked is I am now on my second rebuild of this app after my app would no longer build due to it deleting files I have included in my solution when I build the solution. So this time I want to get it right, and learn the best practices etc.

Many thanks in advance, and sorry for the "newb-ness".

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are things that you need to consider :

1. Do you need to persist data in that INI file.

   If that is the case - then you should consider to have that INI file in some
   other place the in the actual executable path. Every new deploy version or
   build is a new file.
   Maybe on startup to create a file if not exists with default values (if
   needed) somewhere else for example `TEMP`. That would fix your issues with
   building and rewriting the file.
2. If you don't need to persist data then `Copy if newer` is fine option.

Comment: Thanks @j-memisevic I will maybe look to create the file at runtime with some default settings. Just trying to get my head around the design, but I think I can make it work. Will report back once I have tried

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @j-memisevic's suggestions, I now have a solution I believe.

On the form load event for my main form (so app startup), I'm now doing this:

```
if (!File.Exists(gloabl.AppIniFile)
{
  var appIni = new IniFile(gloabl.AppIniFile);
  string projectsCSV = @"E:\Projects\projectlist.csv";
  appIni.Write("Projects_List_CSV", projectsCSV, "Application_Settings");
}
```

So checking if the file already exists and if it does leaving it alone, otherwise creating with a default setting.